# Background image css issue on iphone/ipad (not responsive)

Tags: css, ios

I've got a site which although not responsive, should just show a scaled version of the desktop site when viewed on iphone or ipad. The problem is that my main background image is being compressed for some reason. If I resize the browser I can't recreate this issue, so am just struggling to figure out what's going on iOS which is causing it. The site is  - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Added info: the issue seems to be with div.bg-main and it's background image settings, set on line 243 of style.css

Comment: Your stylesheets aree set to screen. Try setting them to 'all'. Also your graphics are far too big as @SCott Simpson said. Might be worth doing something about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS has a 2 megapixel limit on background images. Your image is 1587*1340 = 2,126,580 pixels - a bit too much. It therefore shrinks it.

You can use the `background-size` property to fix the size back up to what you’re expecting. You’ll lose some detail but it’ll be the correct size. Add this to your CSS:

```
.bg-main { -webkit-background-size: 1587px 1340px }
```

Comment: …and, like Scott above mentions, there are a few PNGs that are over a meg in file size. I’d recommend saving those out as a JPGs and running the entire site’s images through a crusher regardless.

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't realised about the iOS limit till now. Your CSS rule has improved things in that the text is all now sitting on the light yellow part of the bg, and is legible. Still unsure as to why the outer sections of the bg image aren't visible though, any ideas? And yeah, definitely need to get the images sorted out throughout the site, far too big generally

Comment: The first width on in the DOM tree is `.main { width: 1075px; }`. This is inside the size of the background image so the outside will get clipped. IF you need to see those then you could use a meta viewport declaration to expant the initial viewport up to include them. E.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1587, initial-scale=1">` (untested, I don’t have an iPad to hand).

Comment: Many thanks. I added the meta tag, changed the width to 1287 (which works nicely in the iphone viewport) and removed the initial scale. Although this seems to be working fine on my iphone, I'm wondering if this is maybe a problem for other viewport sizes, such as iPad (or retina displays?). Guess I'll need to get hold of an iPad to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can chop your big image with 2 parts and add 2 backgrounds to a div.

Like this:

```
background: url(1.jpg) top center, url(2.jpg) bottom center
```

Answer (score 0):

That image is huge, maybe that is the issue. Try reducing the size with 'save for web' (try getting the design to work with a .jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I've inherited this site and the images definitely need to be optimised. I didn't think that would be the issue here...but after you mentioning it, a google search shows the there's a bug in mobile safari that shrinks background images bigger than a certain size